# Is there some Multilingual manager

Tags: php, json, multilingual

I'm now creating multilingual web application, so I have many particular files, for example

lang.en.php

```
<?php

//
// Language : English - US
//

$lang = array();

// Language preferences
// 
$lang['LANG_NAME'] = 'English';
$lang['LANG_NAME_LOCAL'] = 'English';
$lang['LANG_ABBR'] = 'en';
$lang['LANG_NAT_CODE'] = 'us';

// Site

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Dining support';

// Menu

$lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Home';
$lang['MENU_TODAY'] = 'Today';
$lang['MENU_OTHER'] = 'Other';
.
.
.
?>
```

or lang.en.json (for javascript translations)

```
{
    "PAGE_TITLE" : "Dining Support",
    "LANG_SWITCHING_TO" : "Switching language to: ",
    "SEARCH" : "Search",
.
.
.
}
```

and the same in a few other languages.

My question is - does exists some kind of Multilingual Management Software inside which I can open my content and edit all data side by side? For example I wish to open all lang.meal.actions.xy.php or lang.something.xy.json where xy means language mark and then I wish to edit all translations of one string directly in one place. I tried to Google it, by I'm unable to find some solution :( If you don't know about that software, what way to manage languages you are using?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414079/most-efficient-way-to-do-language-file-in-php